# I'm making an macOS app. Is that possible to use a different app icon on different version of OS?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, wwdc

I've been working on an macOS app for a while. And recently Apple released the first beta version of Big Sur, so I changed my app icon into rounded rectangle shape, just like every other apps in Big Sur.

Now I wonder if it is possible to let my app use rounded rectangle shape in macOS 11.0+, and use another icon in previous versions?

> I noticed that Apple's *Developer.app* is already doing this.

EDIT: I noticed that Apple's *Developer.app* app icon doesn't change automatically. You have to reinstall it from the App Store.

Comment: I'm currently using Apple Developer app, and Xcode 12 beta on macOS Catalina, and they're using the same re-designed icon used in Big Sur. There's no difference.

Comment: @jtouzy That's probably because I installed Big Sur on another disk partition, so I have to reinstall the Developer app.

Comment: Would love to know the answer as well. On Big Sur they've made the icons a bit slimmer so that when using Big Sur icon on Catalina, they look rather small :(